# Most efficient way to draw lines from array of points in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

Given an `NSMutableArray` of dynamic `CGPoint`s, what is the fastest and most efficient way to draw lines from `array[0]` to `array[1]`, `array[1]` to `array[2]`, etc.? Should I rewrite my function in C or C++ for better performance? Currently my framerate suffers dramatically when there are more than ~20 points in the array. I am using cocos2d v2.0.0-rc2 and I currently have:

```
-(void)draw
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [points count]; i+=2)
    {
        CGPoint startFromArray = [[points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint endFromArray = [[points objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue];

        ccDrawLine(startFromArray, endFromArray);
    }

    [super draw];
}
```

Comment: Did you try using plain C arrays? And btw, how do you store CGPoints in NSMutableArray? Is that an extension you wrote?

Comment: to Anthony: if you go to OpenGL level, you will be able to do this by a simple function call, passing a C Array of points.

to DrummerB, you can use CGPoints as objects by encapsulating them to a NSValue instance: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myPoint] - and to retrieve the value: [myValue CGPointValue]

Comment: @DrummerB I have not yet - is that the best course of action? And I am using `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use iteration here. Cocos2d has a built-in function called `ccDrawPoly()`. You can use it like this:

```
CGPoint *verts = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint) * [points count]);

for (int i = 0; i < [points count]; i++) {
    verts[i] = [[points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
}

ccDrawPoly(verts, [points count], NO);

free(verts);
```

Obviously, you'll get even better performance if you store your CGPoints in a C array instead of boxing and unboxing them from NSValues, but if you really need the mutability, that can't be helped.

As for the third argument of `ccDrawPoly()`, setting it to `YES` will connect the start and end points of the array, making a closed polygon, while using `NO` will just make a bunch of open lines.

Comment: Cocos2D also implements a custom mutable array class, which is more efficient then NSMutableArray. I think it's called ccArray.

Comment: @DrummerB It's actually called `CCArray`, and it is slightly faster than `NSMutableArray` in *some* cases. However, it's not a perfect replacement. [Here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/depth-ios-cocos2d-performance-analysis-test-project/#array) are some very useful performance tests.